# Python SQLAlchemy slow when running query filtering on many values

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am having very slow running SQLAlchemy queries against a postgres database, with execution time of 1h or more. Postgres has 64GB of RAM and it is running against NVMe storage. The example query is

```
        signal_values_df = pd.read_sql(session.query(Signals.date, Signals.nyx_id, Signals.signal)
                                               .filter(Signals.signal_name_id == signal_name_id)
                                               .filter(Signals.construction_date_id == construction_date_id)
                                               .filter(Signals.date >= min_running_date)
                                               .filter(Signals.nyx_id.in_([s.nyx_id for s in stocks]))
                                               .filter(Signals.date <= max_running_date).statement, session.bind)
```

with the Signals table being

```
    class StockSignalsAbsoluteVolatility(db.Model):
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        date = Column(Date, nullable=False)
        nyx_id = Column(String, nullable=False)
        signal = Column(Float, nullable=False)
        signal_name_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
        construction_date_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

        __tablename__ = 'stock_signals_absolutevolatility'
        __table_args__ = (Index('stock_signals_absolute_volatility_idx', 'date', 'nyx_id', 'signal_name_id', 'construction_date_id', unique=True), {'schema': 'signal'})
```

The table holds millions of rows.

I have narrowed it down to the IN statement but I am not really sure how I could restructure the query. I did read about the EXISTS statement but all the examples were against a single or 2 to 3 values. In my case it is a list of unknown size, usually in the hundreds or in the low thousands.

The subquery for the number of IDs is OK at 3sec (the non-distinct values are 16 million)

```
quant=> select distinct(nyx_id) from universe.universes u where universe_name_id = 24;
    nyx_id     
---------------
 NYX9320860337
...
 NYX2347270551
 NYX923635888
 NYX1201820422
 NYX7604653677
Time: 3643.824 ms (00:03.644)
```

The number of distinct values of identifiers

```
quant=> select count(distinct(nyx_id)) from universe.universes u where universe_name_id = 24;
 count 
-------
  2278
(1 row)

Time: 14750.523 ms (00:14.751)
```

The query using an EXISTS statement takes 1 minute (I can live with that).

```
quant=> select * from signal.stock_signals_absolutemomentum s where exists (select distinct(nyx_id) from universe.universes u where universe_name_id = 24 and s.nyx_id = u.nyx_id);
    id    |    date    |    nyx_id     | signal | signal_name_id | construction_date_id 
----------+------------+---------------+--------+----------------+----------------------
 31270660 | 2009-09-07 | NYX1124647476 |    NaN |              3 |                   84
 31270661 | 2009-09-07 | NYX2061512636 |    NaN |              3 |                   84
...
 31242133 | 2009-08-19 | NYX8076139540 |    NaN |              3 |                   84
 31242134 | 2009-08-19 | NYX6797298401 |    NaN |              3 |                   84
 31242135 | 2009-08-19 | NYX3754690132 |    NaN |              3 |                   84
Time: 58533.701 ms (00:58.534)
```

The query using an IN statement takes forever (around 1 hour)

```
quant=> select * from signal.stock_signals_absolutemomentum where nyx_id in (select distinct(nyx_id) from universe.universes where universe_name_id = 24);
^CCancel request sent
ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
Time: 1810328.516 ms (30:10.329)
quant=>
```

But how do I refactor the python/SQLAlchemy query?

Comment: When optimising db queues, it is best to first try doing it with pain sql. Once you have that running fast, go on to configure sqlalchemy to use equally good swl queries. Anyway, in the end, it is very likely that your solution is to create some indexes.

Comment: To echo @zvone's comment, this question would probably be better framed as a pure PostgreSQL/SQL question, with information provided as described in the [tag:sql] [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info).

Comment: @snakecharmerb I have the SQL and I can tell it doesn't like the IN statement. This is rather well documented. My problem is that I am looking for how to do it differently from within a python application. In that case the list of identifiers is abstracted, they could be coming from anywhere, another query, a unit test, user input etc.

Comment: `WITH id_val AS (select distinct(nyx_id) as id  from universe.universes where universe_name_id = 24) select * from signal.stock_signals_absolutemomentum where nyx_id = id_val.id`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thank you but my problem is that the original query in python land using the in_() method on a list of string identifiers is very slow. The raw SQL queries were examples running against the table to highlight the problem. Using a subquery is indeed faster but my list is not coming from a subquery, it is provided somehow by the caller upstream.

Comment: Create a temporary table from the list and join against that?